# Google Client API in OSGI

Tags: java, maven, google-api, osgi, aem

I'm having trouble providing the dependencies needed for OAuth Client Library for Java within an OSGI application framework (AEM).

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/setup

I don't want to manually convert each dependency to an OSGI bundle, BND. So I'm using maven-bundle-plugin to embed these into my bundle. My process so far has been to watch the error.log for messages about 'Unresolved constraint in bundle.' Then track down the missing package, add the maven dependency, and add it to the Embed-Dependency section. That seemed to work for google-http-client and google-oauth-client. GSON (or Jackson2 ) cannot be resolved this way, and I get the message...

**Update:**

As Neil pointed out I needed to embed a different dependency for GSON (google-http-client-gson). Thank you!

However it's still not able to deploy, and currently reporting this message...

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.mypackage.services [394]: Unable to resolve 394.130: missing requirement [394.130] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=sun.misc)

It seems others have had trouble with this, and possible related to [Guava in OSGi](http://apache-felix.18485.x6.nabble.com/What-do-I-do-about-strange-package-in-Import-Package-td4835259.html) I have tried making sun.misc optional.

```
<Import-Package>sun.misc.*;resolution:=optional,*</Import-Package>
```

But the bundle fails to start, and provides the error message 'Unresolved constraint in bundle.'  At this point my questions are...

**Has anyone had success in deploying Google CLient API for Java in OSGI? If so, how?**

**Alternatively. I would appreciate suggestions about this `sun.misc` package, and it's possible relation to using Guava in OSGI**

---

my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.2-b06</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.11_1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.avalon-framework</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1_1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.mypackage.services.osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Embed-Dependency>    
                        google-api-client;scope=compile,
                        google-oauth-client;scope=compile,
                        google-http-client;scope=compile,
                        google-api-client-gson;scope=compile,                 
                        gson;scope=compile,
                        httpclient;scope=compile, 
                    </Embed-Dependency>
                    <Sling-Test-Regexp>.*Test</Sling-Test-Regexp>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Portions from the MANIFEST.MF

```
Embed-Dependency: google-api-client;scope=compile,google-api-client-java
 6;scope=compile,google-oauth-client;scope=compile,google-oauth-client-j
 ava6;scope=compile,google-http-client;scope=compile,google-http-client-
 gson;scope=compile,google-http-client-jackson2;scope=compile,gson;scope
 =compile,guava;scope=compile,httpclient;scope=compile,httpcore;scope=co
 mpile,
Embedded-Artifacts: google-api-client-1.20.0.jar;g="com.google.api-clien
 t";a="google-api-client";v="1.20.0",google-api-client-java6-1.20.0.jar;
 g="com.google.api-client";a="google-api-client-java6";v="1.20.0",google
 -oauth-client-1.20.0.jar;g="com.google.oauth-client";a="google-oauth-cl
 ient";v="1.20.0",google-oauth-client-java6-1.20.0.jar;g="com.google.oau
 th-client";a="google-oauth-client-java6";v="1.20.0",google-http-client-
 1.20.0.jar;g="com.google.http-client";a="google-http-client";v="1.20.0"
 ,google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar;g="com.google.http-client";a="googl
 e-http-client-gson";v="1.20.0",google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar;g
 ="com.google.http-client";a="google-http-client-jackson2";v="1.20.0",gs
 on-2.3.jar;g="com.google.code.gson";a="gson";v="2.3",guava-18.0.jar;g="
 com.google.guava";a="guava";v="18.0",httpclient-4.5.jar;g="org.apache.h
 ttpcomponents";a="httpclient";v="4.5",httpcore-4.4.1.jar;g="org.apache.
 httpcomponents";a="httpcore";v="4.4.1"
Import-Package: com.adobe.cq.sightly;version="[2.2,3)",com.day.cq.common
 s;version="[5.7,6)",com.day.cq.commons.date;version="[5.7,6)",com.day.c
 q.dam.api;version="[1.2,2)",com.day.cq.search;version="[1.1,2)",com.day
 .cq.search.result;version="[1.1,2)",com.day.cq.tagging;version="[5.7,6)
 ",com.day.cq.wcm.api;version="[1.2,2)",com.day.cq.wcm.api.components;ve
 rsion="[5.7,6)",com.day.cq.wcm.commons;version="[5.7,6)",com.day.cq.wcm
 .foundation;version="[5.7,6)",com.fasterxml.jackson.core;version="[2.1,
 3)",javax.annotation,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.jcr;version="
 [2.0,3)",javax.naming,javax.naming.directory,javax.naming.ldap,javax.ne
 t,javax.net.ssl,javax.security.auth.x500,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.ht
 tp,javax.xml.parsers,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons
 .httpclient;version="[3.1,4)",org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods;ver
 sion="[3.1,4)",org.apache.commons.httpclient.params;version="[3.1,4)",o
 rg.apache.commons.io;version="[1.4,2)",org.apache.commons.logging;versi
 on="[1.1,2)",org.apache.sling.api;version="[2.3,3)",org.apache.sling.ap
 i.request;version="[2.4,3)",org.apache.sling.api.resource;version="[2.5
 ,3)",org.apache.sling.api.servlets;version="[2.1,3)",org.apache.sling.a
 pi.wrappers;version="[2.5,3)",org.apache.sling.jcr.api;version="[2.2,3)
 ",org.apache.sling.junit.annotations;version="[1.0,2)",org.ietf.jgss,or
 g.junit;version="[4.8,5)",org.junit.runner;version="[4.8,5)",org.osgi.f
 ramework;version="[1.5,2)",org.osgi.service.component;version="[1.1,2)"
 ,org.slf4j;version="[1.6,2)",org.w3c.dom,org.xml.sax,sun.misc
```

Comment: So what's the question? Why not just continue the process for `com.google.api.client.json.gson`?

Comment: I tried adding google-api-client-gson. and embedding it. But that process does not seem to work. And i still get the error posted. I wonder if it's because google-api-client-gson depends on google-api-client

Comment: did you check if appropriate bundles provided by servicemix are available?

Comment: Well the JAR file `google-api-client-gson` doesn't contain the package you need! It only has a single package, `com.google.api.client.googleapis.notifications.json.gson`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally have it working. I've posted the code in case it helps others, or perhaps to find better ways to do it.

The dependencies...

```
<!-- Embedded Google Client API JAR's -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.avalon-framework</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1_1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.2-b06</version>
</dependency>
```

the maven-bundle-plugin settings

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
          <instructions>
              <Bundle-Activator>com.r2i.michigan.lsa.services.osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
              <Embed-Dependency>                             
                  *;scope=compile|runtime,
              </Embed-Dependency>
                <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive> 
                <Import-Package>
                  sun.misc;resolution:=optional,
                  com.sun.jdmk.comm;resolution:=optional,*
                </Import-Package>                       
              <Sling-Test-Regexp>.*Test</Sling-Test-Regexp>
          </instructions>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```