# How to import a class from third party jar file in an OSGi component

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aem, aem-developer-tools

I am using https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/ to create a project. Once created, I have the following structure in eclipse:

[image]

I want to be able to use the GoogleMaps API in my component. So I add the dependency for it in `hometest.core/pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've also added everything to the `_exportcontents` in `hometest.core/pom.xml`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                    <_exportcontents>
                                    *
                    </_exportcontents>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I then import `com.google.maps.model.GeocodingResult` into `HelloServiceProxy.java` as shown below:

[image]

I install the package to local instance of aem using `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage`

However, when I try to add the component to the page I get the following error:

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:      Only a type can be
>   imported. com.google.maps.model.GeocodingResult resolves to a package

Below is screenshot of the error:

[image]

**Update 1**

I started with another brand new AEM project and did the following things:

- in core/pom.xml added configuration settings for `maven-bundle-plugin` like this

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
              <instructions>
          <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
          <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
          <_exportcontents>
           *
          </_exportcontents>
          </instructions>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- Added google maps dependency like this:

  ```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.7</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- deployed with this `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage`

When I try to add component to the page I get errors:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Only a type can be imported. com.google.maps.model.GeocodingResult resolves to a package
    Only a type can be imported. org.demo.anothertest.core.HelloService resolves to a package
    HelloService cannot be resolved to a type
    HelloService cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: I've seen this problem before. Sometimes a superficial change to force the recompilation of the view or ui helps.  I don't have great understanding about it. But it could be that the dependency in core and the ui package is trying to use a service that is not registered when the ui jsp gets compiled

Comment: @ChristopherRockwell how did you solve it?

Comment: You may be interested in a question I recently posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191299/google-client-api-in-osgi but I didn't export the jars, only embedded. So they can only be used within the service/core bundle. .... Additionally in regards about "Only a type can be imported." I've 'solved' that before by redeploying just the view, and in another case just saving a whitespace change in the JSP (forcing a recompile).  But if it were me, I would embed (not export) the jars and use them within the same bundle if possible, even thou that's not really the osgi way

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the classes from `google-maps-services` bundle are not available to the `hometest.core` bundle. It might very well be that embedding bundles does not work at this point.

Can you try deploying a separate bundle which embeds `google-maps-services` and see if that works?

Comment: I tried another bundle and have updated what I did in the question. Error is the same as before..

Comment: Can you open up the jar contents of hometest bundle and see if it's  manifest.mf has google-maps-services packages listed in its "Import-Package" header. If its there with a proper version, then check if the same packages are present in the export-package section of google's bundle. If this does not work, give a try for <Bundle-ClassPath> attribute of maven-bundle-plugin instead of using <embed-dependency>.

Comment: @Anthony were you able to clear the jsp compilation error?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the update. What I mean was to deploy another bundle using mvn sling:install or the Felix Web Console and try again.