# Implement Authentication for servlet on publish instance CQ5/AEM

Tags: authentication, servlets, aem

I have a scenario and any suggestions in implementing that will be of great help. I have a servlet created on publish that will have POST requests coming from a lot of other third party applications. This servlet just stores the incoming posted data in JCR. I have successfully created this servlet but now the requirement is to make this servlet secured so that only applications hitting this servlet with particular username and password should be entertained.

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your replies. In the end I implemented the below code for authentication in cq :

```js
                final String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
                if (authorization != null && authorization.startsWith("Basic")) {
                  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(authorization);
                  if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String basic = st.nextToken();
                    if (basic.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
                      String decodedStr = Base64.decode(st.nextToken());
                      LOGGER.info("Credentials: " + decodedStr);
                      int p = decodedStr.indexOf(":");
                      if (p != -1) {
                        String login = decodedStr.substring(0, p).trim();
                        String password = decodedStr.substring(p + 1).trim();

                        Credentials credentials = new SimpleCredentials(login, password.toCharArray());
                        adminSession = repository.login(credentials);

                        if (null != adminSession) {
                          // means authenticated and do your stuff here                                  
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Also in the webservice code which is calling the servlet of publish, below is the code on how I am supplying the credentials in auth headers :

```js
                String authStr = usrname+":"+password;
    // encode data on your side using BASE64
    byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(authStr.getBytes());
    String authEncoded = new String(bytesEncoded);                                                       
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+authEncoded);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);      
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");      
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new                 OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());  
    writer.write("jsondata={sample:jsoncontent}");  
    writer.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go for it:

Ask those 3rd party applications to send you the username and password so you can validate them on your servlet, then decide if you will allow or reject the request.

*from the servlet calling (the 3rd party application)*

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ... 

        request.setAttribute("username", "a_valid_user");
        request.setAttribute("password", "a_valid_password");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("yourApp/YourServlet").forward(req, resp);
}
```

*On your servlet:*

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

if("a_valid_user".equals(username) && "a_valid_password".equals(password) {
     // validate and go further
} else {
     // do not process the request
}
```

The above example is valid just in case you can validate them on your side.

> If this sample doesn't answer to your question, please provide more information about those 3rd party applications and the way you want to validate them.

Comment: That way will be not very secure I guess. That password will be visible to the unintended people if anyone intercepts request. I was looking for a better way.

Comment: If you have an https connection, then the data traveling on the network will be encrypted.

Comment: Yes @Petre thats what I was thinking. For now I have put the credentials in Authorization in the connection to my servlet and then encoding it Base64 then in my CQ5 servlet I am decoding the authorization username password, checking if the user is valid in CQ5 users and only then returning the data. Hopefully HTTPS should take care of the worry for credential sniffing.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Google Client Library. I used it for authentication of users in an AEM publish instance. After the third party server is authenticated, you could use a separate AEM service account to handle POST processing.

Here' a SO post I made about integrating those libraries into AEM.
[Google Client API in OSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191299/google-client-api-in-osgi)

With this you should be able set up authentication of the third party service account... as discussed here
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I haven't actually done server to server auth in AEM, but it should be possible. But in a separate project (non AEM) I've used the Google Client Library for authenticating Service Accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a two step process:

- Step 1: Authentication and generate a token, you can use 3rd party service also to generate token.
- Step 2: Call your servlet with this token, the servlet will validate token first and then use post data.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Actually new to this thing so don't really know where to begin from for this token based authentication. But apart from this can you check my approach in reply to Petre and suggest if that way will do or if thats not an recommended way ?

Comment: I read that solution and it make sense but i am bit worried about server overloading because of such requests + authentication, have u identified your audience and done scaling based on that?
You can also think about authentication of such request at apache level so that publish server get filtered & correct authenticated request only.

Comment: I dont need to worry about overloading because only one SAP application will be accessing this, that too not so often.